# Finding the number of Bracelet five beads different colors

Tags: combinatorics, cyclic-groups, permutations

Consider a bracelet  of 5 colored beads.
How many different bracelets are there if all the 5 colors are different?
            Take into account rotations and flipping.
            Verify the correctness of your solution considering the same problem
            for a bracelet of 4 beads with 4 different colors.

My answer is : There are possible (n-1)!/2 bracelets for n distinct colors, like in our case.
Thus for n=5, there are possible 4!/2=12 different bracelets.
I think that I'm missing something.

I would like to know to deal with such problems.

Comment: See Polya enumeration: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem

Comment: Have you had a chance to follow up on the pointers you have been given here? Anything to say?

Answer (score 2):

As @Doc notes in a comment, Polya enumeration is a way to solve this kind of question. But the particular questions you ask can be answered without it and in fact your answer looks good to me. We can always rotate the bracelet so the red bead is at the top. That leaves $(n-1)!$ ways to place the other beads, but they come in pairs where you get the one from the other by flipping in the vertical axis. So, $${(n-1)!\over2}$$

Why do you think you are missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong. When I tried listing out possibilities for 3 beads it did not work.

(n-1)!/2
   =(3-1)!/2
 =1  (their should be 2 possibilities RGY and RYG)

Also for 4 beads it does not work. I may have made a mistake here is my work...

(n-1)!/2
   =(4-1)!/2
 =3

However, assuming there is a red (R), Green (G), Yellow (Y) and Blue(B) bead here are the possibilities.

RGBY
RGYB
RBYG
RBGY
RYBG
RYBG

That is six possibilities. 
The actual equation should be (n-1)!
for 3 it would then be
(3-1)!
=2 (which is correct)
and for 4 it would be (4-1)!=6(which is correct)